# Spinner em Popup

Tags: java, android, popup

Tenho uma tela onde a mesma possui uma `Gridview` e um `ImageButton`.

Pois bem, ao clicar nesse `ImageButton` abro um `PopUp` que contem duas `spinner` e um `ImageButton`.

Essas `spinners` sao populados atraves de um web service que é chamado após o usuário efetuar o login, até aí tudo bem.

Quando seleciono as informações nas duas `spinners` e clico no `button` não consigo recuperar os valores (descricao ou id) que populei com meu `adapter` sendo que, se utilizo o mesmo código fora de um PopUp, consigo recuperar as informações mas quando uso em um popup não.

Segue o código do meu adapter para minha spinner

```
package br.com.projeto.adapter;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import br.com.projeto.entidade.DadosFiliais;
import br.com.projeto.entidade.DadosPortifolio;
import br.com.projeto.osportifolio.R;

public class SpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    ArrayList<DadosFiliais> data = new ArrayList<DadosFiliais>();
    public SpinnerAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<DadosFiliais> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    DadosFiliais datas = new DadosFiliais(); 
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
    TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);                      
    text1.setText(data.get(position).getDsFilial());
    return view;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 32;
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return  "TextView";
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {     
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_spinner, null);

    TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.row_s.dados_spinner);
    TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.row_s.dados_spinner_2);

    text1.setText(data.get(position).getDsFilial());
    text2.setText(data.get(position).getCdFilial());
    return view;
}
```

}

Código usado para pegar os valores das spinners

```
String localidadeStr = txtLocalidade.getText().toString();
String movimentoStr = txtMovimento.getText().toString();
localidade = Integer.parseInt(localidadeStr); 
movimento = Integer.parseInt(movimentoStr);
```

ao invés de trazer o valor ele recupera o valor "TextView"

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que a String `"TextView"` que é retornada do método `getItem` do seu Adapter é o problema ao recuperar o item selecionado.

Mude o seu adapter para:

```
public class SpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    ArrayList<DadosFiliais> data = new ArrayList<DadosFiliais>();

    public SpinnerAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<DadosFiliais> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Porque instanciar um DadosFilias?
        //DadosFiliais datas = new DadosFiliais(); 
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
        TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);                      
        text1.setText(data.get(position).getDsFilial());

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        //return 32;
        // Mude para retornar a quantidade de itens da lista.
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        //return "TextView";
        // Em vez de retornar a String "TextView" fixa, retorna o dado da lista
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {     
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_spinner, null);

        TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.row_s.dados_spinner);
        TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.row_s.dados_spinner_2);

        text1.setText(data.get(position).getDsFilial());
        text2.setText(data.get(position).getCdFilial());

        return view;
    }
}
```

Para acessar o objeto `DadosFiliais` selecionado no Spinner:

```
// Recupera seu spinner
Spinner sp = (...);

// Recupera o objeto selecionado direto do Adapter
DadosFilias objetoSelecionado = sp.getSelectedItem();
```

Como seu adapter faz muito acesso ao `findViewById`, imagina uma lista muito grande, percorrer a árvore de `Views` torna a listagem lenta. Para isso recomendo que olhe o padrão [`View Holder`](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder)